# Django Collectstatic Error IBM bluemix

Tags: django, ibm-cloud

I am getting this error when i am trying to deploy the django app on IBM Bluemix.
Please see the log file

[image: Log file]

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual log file as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

goto terminal and type following commands:

**mkdir -p /home/vcap/app/static**

**sudo chmod +777 -r /home/vcap/app/static**

This will create the missing directory and grant all permissions on it. So this missing file exception being raised as shown in the png will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using IBM Bluemix DevOps at hub.jazz.net, in your project folder create a static folder "static" [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwr74.png) create a blank file may be you can name it as ".nothing" or something like that. (In my case I have static files so I don't have to create the blank ".nothing" file.)